# cpp Binary Search Problem, counting occurence of input element in a given array

Tags: c++

I just want to know what the problem in this code;
I got it from youtube,but the problem is when i pass the value of x.
It not doing anything its showing blank screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

// use binary search 
int find(int arr[], int n, int x, bool leftmost){
    int low = 0; 
    int high = n-1;
    int mid = low + (high - low)/2;
    int res = -1;

    while (low <= high){
        if (arr[mid] == x){
            res = mid;

            if (leftmost){  // it flag is true we will find the left most 
                high = mid - 1;
            }else{             //else we will find the right most 
                low = mid+1;
            }

        }
        if (arr[mid] > x){
            high = mid - 1;

        }
        else{
            low = mid +1;
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {2,2,3,3,3,3};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int x;
    cout << "Enter the number "<< endl;
    cin >> x;
    int leftidx = find(arr, n, x, true);
    int rightidx = find(arr, n, x, false);
    cout << (rightidx - leftidx) +1;

    return 0;
}
```

Having this problem in few more programs.
So if you have time help me.
Thanks

Comment: Compile the code and start the program in you debugger. Step line by line through the code.

Comment: I'd advise you to read the following article to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not updating your `mid` variable, so your loop goes infinite. Add this to the end of the loop:

```
   /...
   else{
       low = mid +1;
   }
   mid = (low + high) / 2; // add this line
```

Also keep things simple, the following code:

```
    int mid = low + (high - low)/2;
```

is equivalent to :

```
    int mid = (low + high)/2;
    //or just
    int mid = high / 2;
```

Don't add unnecessary complexity to your code.